# retrieve file line one by one using C#?

Tags: c#

I have a file  name **abc.txt**. On that file have some lines like this:

> jani
>  50,south carolina,USA
>   karim
>  16,roam,Italy
>  fara
>   52,sydny,Australia

First line is name and second line is address. Now I need the info name on a string let's say **nameString** and address is let's say **addressString**. How can I do it using C#?
I write a code in PHP its working smoothly. I need the same thing in C#. For yours clarification here is the php code:

```
$file=file_get_contents('abc.txt');

$arr=explode("\n",$file);
for ($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i=$i+2)
{

    $name=$arr[$i];
    $address=$arr[$i+1];
    echo $name ."<br/>";
    echo $address. "<br/>";

}
```

How can I do the same thing in C#????
Another question: Is there any function in C# as like as explode in php?

Thanks in advance 
riad

Comment: obously i will do.pls do it for me thanks

Comment: Done. Code posted below.

Comment: ok wait i m going to test --anyway thanks for your kind effort--riad:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] arr = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
for (int i = 0; i<arr.Length; i += 2)
{
  // do whatever you need here
}
```

Comment: Just a warning; this solution isn't scalable - depending on the size of the file, this will potentially use up a lot of memory.

The reason I use the While, line by agonizing line routine is that you'll only ever have to worry about two strings in memory.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("c:\\myfile.txt"));

            string line = reader.ReadLine();

            while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                // do stuff. 
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how i get the name and address??

Comment: Just to be clear, ReadLine will read up to any newline characters, so you don't need to worry about splitting or exploding.

Just create storage variables for name and address outside of the while loop.

Comment: i wrote a solution previously but its give me ambiguous results.
It's cannot be solved by while loop.pls see my code

StreamReader SR;
            string S;
            SR = File.OpenText("C:\\abc.txt");
            S = SR.ReadLine();
            int counter = 1;
            while (S != null)
            {
                if ((counter % 2) != 0)
                    MessageBox.Show(S);
                else
                    MessageBox.Show(S);
                S = SR.ReadLine();
                counter++;
            }
            SR.Close();

Comment: I've got a better idea, but my Boss has just given me an urgent task.

Separate the actual Reader.ReadLine into a method that returns a simple class or struct, and then your while loop will just check if the returned object is null or not.  let me know if you need a code example; will have to post it later though.

Comment: thanks for your effort...anyway VladV give the proper solution that i looking for..thanks bro for your effort:)...riad

Answer (score 0):

you can use a filestream to read it

Answer (score 0):

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader("bla.txt"))
{
     string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

     string[] rows = content.Split('\n');

     foreach (var s in rows)
     {
          //output it somewhere
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A replacement for implode is, as Joakim answered, Split.

You should also consider the newline string, and use [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) (that could be \n or \r or \r\n)

Also, usually 'translating' from one language to another isn't the best solution. If you want to use the equivalent of implode in this case, you wouldn't read the file line by line, but use ReadToEnd() and then Split the result. That would ignore the ReadLine method, which is created for this purpose.